# DOM Problems, Not sure if object exists yet? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm tearing hairs with this one, beginner alert.

Trying to build a basic quiz using straight JS and not JQuery, not having much luck.

I can't figure out how to correctly loop through the radio buttons to check for user selection. I'm pretty sure I've got the code right, but it's not working.

Is it something to do with the fact the 'name' in question is being generated by .innerHTML so technically non-existent on page load?

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AU2ve/

And here's my loop, which as I said, I'm sure is ok.

```
// Check which answer selected (Test)

function checkAnswer() {

    var answerChoices = document.getElementsByName('choices');

    for (var j = 0; j < answerChoices.length; j++) {       
         if (answerChoices[i].checked) {
             alert(answerChoices[i].value);
             break;
        }
     }
 }
```

As I said, I'm still very new to this, hopefully it's a simple solution.

Thanks

Comment: I'm ok with jQuery, well, I get by. I just feel like I *should* know how to do this stuff without it.

Comment: You're updating the DOM with the new question **before** you check to see if the old question was correctly answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out you've got a loop error.

Also you must `checkAnswer();` before updating the options.

Then you should check if you got more questions :

`if (typeof allQuestions[xNum - 1] !== "undefined") {`

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AU2ve/3/

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I thought it had something to do with the order it was being called.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `j`, not `i`.

Just replace `answerChoices[i]` with `answerChoices[j]`.

Comment: `checkAnswer` is called after replacing the question... http://jsfiddle.net/AU2ve/4/

Answer (score 0):

Updated it. Indexes i and j are mixed. Try [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AU2ve/5/)

```
for (var j = 0; j < answerChoices.length; j++) {
    if (answerChoices[j].checked) {
        alert(answerChoices[j].value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Also check for length of question pool before rendering:

```
if (allQuestions.length > xNum - 1) {
```

Also error in your HTML formatting:

```
    newHtml += '<label><input type="radio" name="choices" value="' + allQuestions[xNum - 1].choices[i] + '" />' + allQuestions[xNum - 1].choices[i] + '<label>';
```

As you will notice I also surrounded your inputs with label:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="choices" value="David Cameron">David Cameron</label>
```

This way you can click on the name to select a radio.